# Java: Control selection and iterations? What does it mean?

Tags: java

I have to reach certain fields in a competence grid from my school and there is a certain question where I am not sure how to interpete it:

One of the skills they want me to prove I can do:

```
Appropriate variables are used to control selection and iterations!
```

I already gathered a lot of knowledge in programming but this sentence is so confusing. What exactly do they mean?

I just need to know how to understand the question. Do they want me to create different loops (while, for, foreach etc) and manipulate them via variables?

Comment: Why don't you want to ask the right person in your school? Surely they know better :)

Comment: @Nikem im not very popular due to my Autism : (

Answer (score 1):

I believe it means having the aptitude of separating between variables that you would use to hold informations (and as such are critical for the system, which may make them accessible from most locations) and basic variables that you would use temporarily for iterations and as counters.